# как проверить введенное ли именно число в input при клике на кнопку

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" placeholder="the enter">
 <button>Send</button>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  var enter=$('input');
  var send=$('button').click(function() {
   var enter_val=enter.val();
   console_log(enter_val);
  });;
  if (enter_val!==null || enter_val==Number()) {
   alert('sent!!!');
  }
  else {
   alert('sorry');
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: type="number" ?

Answer (score 1):

для проверки на "не число" можно применить метод isNaN, который взращивает false для всех числовых значений.

```js
 var input = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0];
 var button = document.getElementsByTagName('BUTTON')[0];
     button.onclick = function(){
  alert(input.value && !isNaN(input.value)? "sent!!!" : "sorry")
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" placeholder="the enter">
 <button>Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var enter = $('input');
var send = $('button').click(function() {
  var enter_val = enter.val() -0; //преобразуем введенное значение из string в integer неявно. Если преобразование не возможно, вернет NaN
  console.log(enter.val());
  if ((enter.val() !== '')&&(!Number.isNaN(enter_val))) {  //если значение НE NaN и не пустая строка
    alert('sent!!!');
  } else { 
    alert('sorry');
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" placeholder="the enter">
  <button>Send</button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Проблема была в области видимости. Переменная `enter_val` проверялась на значение вне функции, в которой была создана.

Comment: Чтобы не ввел каждый раз `sent!!!` :P

Comment: исправила и добавила комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

Тут много вариантов, можно просто поставить `<input type="number"/>`

Можно проверять нажатие кнопок на клавиатуре и не реагировать ни на что кроме цифр, ну или например вот так проверить регуляркой:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" placeholder="the enter">
 <button>Send</button>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  var enter=$('input');
  var send=$('button').click(function() {
  var enter_val=enter.val();
         console.log(enter_val);
  if ((enter_val!==null) && (/^\d+$/.test(enter_val))) {
   alert('sent!!!');
  }
  else {
   alert('sorry');
  }
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```