# Проверка поля ввода?

Tags: javascript

```js
var tut = document.getElementById("one");
tut.addEventListener("keypress", show);
function show(){
  console.log(tut.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="one" type="text">
```

Подскажите, как правильно сделать проверку на то, что бы было введено число, и если это число то работать дальше, если нет то нет

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: для проверки на "не число" можно применить метод isNaN

[нативный метод isNaN для проверки на "не число"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772299/как-проверить-введенное-ли-именно-число-в-input-при-клике-на-кнопку/772325#772325)